# Pip3 Install old version of package

Tags: tensorflow, github, pip

I am trying to install the old version of tensorflow (2.1.0) via pip3
`pip3 install tensorflow==2.1.0` is not working, it does not find versions older than 2.2.

Now I try to do this via GitHub.
I tried those:

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git@v2.1.0
pip3 install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git@releases/tag/v2.1.0
```

None of them works, all of them freeze for one minute and then return:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-req-build-8t5bnpgl/setup.py'
```

Does anyone have a good alternative for this? I want to do it directly via pip3. Using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: You can't install `tensorflow` from source repo, the code should be cloned and compiled with `bazel` to a wheel file.

Comment: Aside from that, 2.2 isn't even released yet. What is the output of `pip3 install tensorflow==2.1.0`?

Answer (score 1):

[`tensorflow` 2.1.0](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.1.0/#files) didn't release wheel for Python 3.8 and you probably have Python 3.8. Downgrade to Python 3.7 or [install `tensorflow` from sources](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source).